# SQLite3 not able to open database

Tags: php, sqlite

In my PHP file (register.php), I have the following:

```
class DB extends SQLite3{
    function __construct(){
        $this->open('/usr/share/nginx/www/cgi-bin/db/userpass.db');
    }
}

$db = new DB();

$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO userpass VALUES(:user, :encrypted_pass)');
$stmt->bindValue(':user', $user);
$stmt->bindValue(':encrypted_pass', $encrypted_pass);

if($stmt->execute() == FALSE) die(1); //line 25
```

Which throws:

```
Warning: SQLite3Stmt::execute(): Unable to execute statement: unable to open database file in /path/to/register.php on line 25
```

I'm using nginx, PHP5, SQLite3, and `php5-sqlite3` from the Raspbian repositories.

Edit: Output of `ls -l /usr/share/nginx/www/cgi-bin/db`:

```
total 4
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 3072 Nov 11 19:17 userpass.db
```

Comment: Did you check that the user executing the php script has the requires rights to create a (database) file at the path you specified?

Comment: @Thomas How would I check? I'm pretty new to this kind of stuff, sorry if this is facepalm-inducing.

Comment: It would help if you could show the actual path you want to use for the database. I assume you have a standard raspian setup and your php scrips are under /var/www - if you created them as a user and php runs as 'www-data', there is no permission to create the database file.

Comment: @Thomas Added the full path.

Comment: can you post the output of ```ls -l /usr/share/nginx/www/cgi-bin/db/``` ?

Comment: @Thomas, sorry, meant to do that earlier. Added.

Comment: If the permission of one of the parent directories forbid access you can get the same result. Please check that the php/nginx user (probably www-data) has acccess to that. Easiest way is to switch to the user and check in the filesystem manually: ```sudo su www-data -s /bin/bash```